# Is pine script editor available in charting library on my custom website

Tags: javascript, pine-script, tradingview-api

can i have a pine script editor on charting library on my website? Just like the one on tradingview website?

Answer (score 0):

If not listed among the widgets here https://www.tradingview.com/widget/, I fear it's impossible